# JavaScript: addEventListener not running

Tags: javascript

Learning Javscript and trying to trigger a click event.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but the following doesn't seem to work.

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/73e7H/1/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li id="nav-item-39">
        <a href="#">Visit</a>
    </li> 
<ul>
```

JS

```
var $visit = document.getElementById('nav-item-39').firstChild;

$visit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    print('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `firstChild` is a text node containing the whitespace after the end of the `li` start tag and the beginning of the link. You need the first child that's an *element*.

On many browsers, that's `firstElementChild`, but if you need support for older browsers you may need a loop.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73e7H/3/) *(using `alert` rather than `print`)*

Another option is to use `querySelector`, which is available on all modern browsers (even IE8 — but of course, IE8 doesn't have `addEventListener`):

```
var $visit = document.querySelector('#nav-item-39 a');

$visit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    print('hello');
});
```

That finds the first `a` element that's a descendant of `#nav-item-39`. If you want to require that it's a direct *child* instead, use the selector string `"#nav-item-39 > a"` instead.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73e7H/2/)

(Just for completeness: `querySelector` finds the first matching element and returns it [or `null` if no match]. There's also `querySelectorAll` which finds all matching elements and returns a static `NodeList`.)

---

Side note: `print`, unless you override it (and I don't think you do in the fiddle), is `window.print` which opens the browser's Print dialog.

Comment: +1 - There's also `.children[0]`, which may or may not have better support than `.firstElementChild`, I can't remember :-P

Answer (score 1):

Try Using firstElementChild instead of firstChild.
firstElementChild will defenitely return element, when firstChild can return text node also.